# Save controller state on page refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm trying to implement a gmail like save message as draft functionality in my form.

**Use Case**: There is one form with certain fields which includes some text box, some image uploads, etc. My problem is how can I retain the values of these if these have been filled by user on a page refresh. Remember page is not yet submitted by user. If it has been submitted then I could have retrieved the values from server but how can I store values in input box now in case no submit button is clicked.

Should there be some api which will save the values regularly or can there be some api which can be invoked only when user is about to close the page or refresh it ?

I have no idea about this and would appreciate any pointers in this.

**Update:**

Based on the suggestions, I tried to explore some tutorials/blogs which can show the preoper design and implementation for using local storage. I found following good links:

http://yeoman.io/codelab/local-storage.html
https://domantasjovaisas.wordpress.com/2014/09/05/angularjs-saving-global-variable-in-localstorage/

Few doubts:
It seems we can store a JSON object in local storage but how can I store a given object for a given user.

Use Case: A user can create multiple messages. I just want to keep the last message which was not saved neither sent. How can I design this so that storage works fine ? For a given userId I want to keep some data in local storage. Is it safe to store a db Id in local storage ?

Please suggest

Comment: I would use LocalStorage to persist the data in the browser. As far as how you do it, you could do it on a timer or you could bind to the input elements' change events.

Comment: Can you share some tutorials/blog posts for same ? It'll be great then.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a library that abstracts over localStorage and defers to cookies if you are looking to support older browsers. Use JSON.stringify and pass it to your storage service. You can also append usernames to the key if you are likely to have multiple users on one machine. It would be good practice anyways.

Examples include:

- https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage
- http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngStorage

You can hook into ng-change, watches, event listeners or use a timer as someone else suggested.

UPDATE: You can find a trivial implementation here, http://scionsoftware.com/Blog/saving-form-state-with-angular-js/

If you're looking to do it for only one string value as you implied, simply remove the JSON.parse and JSON.stringify pieces from the javascript.

Comment: Can you provide some tutorials/blog posts explaining this in more detail ? It'll be of great help.

Comment: Yes, I will get back to you as soon as I put it together.

Comment: Thanks a lot SpykeBytes. Also, can you please take a look at my update in the question

Comment: @dark_shadow I have updated the answer with a blog link